# Why doesn't IdentityServer4 ApiResource work with JwtBearerOption.Audience?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have this config in IdentityServer:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> ApiResources =>
        new ApiResource[]
        {
            new ApiResource
            {
                Name = "MyApi"
            }
        };
```

and this jwt configuration on the ASP.NET Core web API:

```
 services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
       .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
       {
           //identity server
           options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

           //access token recepient
           options.Audience = "https://localhost:5001/resources";

           options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
           {
               ValidateAudience = true,
               ValidateLifetime = true,
           };
       });
```

I'm expecting that the Web API authentication won't accept the token from IdentityServer because the Web API JwtBearerOption.Audience is not equal to "MyApi". But in my config the Audience is only validated if the audience is set to "https://localhost:5001/resources" and will invalidate if I set it to "MyApi"

[IdentityServer4 documentation about related to my question.](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get MyApi into the list of audiences you need to define an ApiScope as will in IdentityServer4 (v4.0x)

See this [articles](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html?highlight=apiscopes) for more details

Comment: If that's the case, the ApiScope(s) is the Audience as well?

Comment: Yes, the ApiScopes becomes the audience, the https://localhost:5001/resources seems to be a standard audience that is always present?

Comment: Though the IS4 docs don't tell how to do it, you gave me an idea, I've added the scopes in the ApiResource configuration as well.

Comment: There is a god and his name is @RonaldAbellano. I've been scouring everything I could find on this and it wasn't until I came across your little gem of knowledge to add the scopes to the ApiResource! THE DOCUMENTATION DOESN'T SAY THAT!!! I've been at this for a couple of days now and you just saved me. Thank you Thank you Thank you.

Comment: This cost me two days. I noticed that I didn't add this code. ".AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources)" so thx, I want to cry
 :(((